# Assets + MSM won't display/upload files on custom sites: Update Indexes not working

Tags: multi-site-manager, assets

I've browsed through quite a few similar questions, but many of these seem to have gone unanswered. I have some new input that might help.

### Situation

I'm running EE2.5.5, Assets 2.05, and Multiple Site Manager (not sure if version is relevant/where to find it) with 3 custom sites.

Like most similar questions, everything seems to be working fine on the default site (let's call this one *Site1*). Every site had their File Upload Directories duplicated from Site1 and are working fine in EE's own File Manager (after syncing every directory).

### The Problem

Assets is not working in any of the site variations.

**What's interesting:** I know why! The "Update Indexes" feature is failing. When I hit "Update Indexes", an AJAX request is made to the wrong domain. This request SHOULD go to "site1.com/", instead of "site2.com/", since the control panel only works from site1 (in my setup).

I've tried adding the config variable `$config['assets_site_url'] = 'http://site1.com/index.php';`, unfortunately to no avail.

### The Question

How/where can I configure Assets to help it send the **Update Indexes** AJAX request to the correct URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was solved by adding $config['assets_site_url'] = 'http://site1.com/index.php'; for real - on the first try something had went wrong for Adrian silently, apparently.

Using the CP to add this option worked as expected.

Comment: I figured out what went wrong, the first time: I had to define it as `http://site1.com/` instead of `http://site1.com/index.php`, since we removed the "index.php" from the URL's as described in this manual: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html Thanks Andris!

Comment: Had exactly this issue, glad this ticket existed :D

Comment: Some Notes that might help someone: this thread led me to try a few things. I got this to work slightly different method. added: $config['assets_site_url'] = '/index.php'; AND $config['assets_cp_path'] = '/admin.php'; of the main site's config file ONLY (not to the msm sites). Also check the head of that file as assets may have already written to it. EE2.7.3 + Assets 2.4